# Vitamin D oral intake, transportation and absorption

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, microbiology, vitamins, fat-metabolism

Several factors affecting vitamin D and its active form absorption and storage

- acidity of stomach (not significant effect)
- cytopathic effects of viruses
- cytopathic effects of bacteria

where the last two reasons can be some reasons which may explain why vitamin D should be administered with bread; to make a surface covering around out vitamin D molecules. 
Probably, the fibers also work in some short of transport media.
They can also partially explain why big dose of vitamin D does not last long time in the normostenic body.

Summary of procedures in administrating vitamin D orally

- with bread (carbohydrates; fibers) - possible protection, better transportation and more to absorbtion
- with oils (fat metabolism could help in destroying extra free radicals; but I see no other sense in administrating vitamin D with fish oils)
- daily (not weekly)

**Why does the lipid-soluble vitamin D not last in the body long time?**